# how to get the files from active folder... the folder name is in hte URL - rootfolder

Tags: web-part, document-library, sandbox-solution

I've a document library and within this document libary I have sub-folders (no subfolders further).

There is 1 documentlibary called DocumentACC and this document libary contains Sub-folders as you see below. These subfolders contains FILES (Word, PPT, XLS etc.) no subfolders within this further.

So when I open the DocumentACC then the Folder it shows e.g. 15 files. now the idea is with my sandbox solution WEBpart which has only 1 button. The idea is when the user clicks on the button he should get all files names + location of that files....

!!!! But only files for that specific folder, where he is !!!!

So I looked and found the Folder is in the URL... But how can I get the files for that folder. So I think the URL with the querystring parameter "RootFolder" is fine, but how can I get the files.... I'm struggling and struggling, can someone bring me on right path... Below is the folder structure and the small code for webpart....

So HOw can I get all files from Folder ACC 2015-11-05??

DocumentACC

```
ACC 2015-12-14

ACC 2015-11-05

ACC 2015-10-15
```

http://SharePoint2013/AccountingSite/DocumentsACC/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FAccountingSite%2FDocumentsACC%2FACC%202015%2D12%2D14&FolderCTID=0x012000BA2FCD357903654890332D0D577C47E9&View=%7B2493FEB5%2DC1D4%2D401E%2D8358%2DCE0BC680FDAD%7D

```
libName = "DocumentsACC";

using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPDocumentLibrary lstDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[libName];

    Label3.Text = lstDocLib.RootFolder.Name;
    foreach (SPListItem item in lstDocLib.Items)
    {
        //Label3.Text = item.Folder.Name;
        if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            //item is a folder
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<BR />" + item.Name;
        }
        else if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
        {
            //item is afile
            Label2.Text = Label1.Text + "<BR />" + item.Name;

            //HERE I NEED TO GET THE FILE NAMES and LOCATION
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SPListItem whose content type is Folder, you can get an SPFolder object using the Folder property:

```
item.Folder
```

With that object, you can get the Files property to retrieve a SPFileCollection object with all of the files inside the folder:

```
item.Folder.Files
```

If your SPListItem is a file, you can get its SPFile object with the File property:

```
item.File
```

Both SPFolder and SPFile have a Url property that will give you the web-relative URL for that object:

```
item.File.Url
item.Folder.Url
```